# ImageMagick: Replace RGB channels with white, retain Alpha

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image created in a Affinity Designer, which has the following channels:

R, G and B:

[image: RGB channels]

Alpha:

[image: Alpha channel]

When I use this image in other places (Unreal Engine), I get small black artifacts on the edge of the shape due to the black part of the RGB channels. The only important information I need is the alpha channel.

How can I use ImageMagick to replace the RGB channels with white, while retaining the alpha channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do the in ImageMagick:

First, since you did not provide the actual image, I will reconstruct it from the rgb.png and alpha.png

```
convert rgb.png alpha.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite image.png
```

Now, to make the rgb part white, simply do:

```
convert image.png -fill white -colorize 100 result.png
```

Now to see that the rgb parts are fully white, we do:

```
identify -verbose result.png
.
.
.
 Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 512
    Gray:
      min: 255  (1)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -4.9152e+52
      skewness: 9.375e+35
      entropy: 0
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 187.152 (0.733931)
      standard deviation: 109.252 (0.42844)
      kurtosis: -0.822401
      skewness: -1.05578
      entropy: 0.336307
```

So the rgb components are a constant 255 (white) and the image is now white with an alpha component.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following...

```
magick \( input.png -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 reset' \) \
       \( input.png -alpha extract \) \
       -compose Copy_Alpha -composite \
       output.png
```

I'm sure there's better ways to do the above. Reading the `input.png` twice, and extracting the alpha channel is bit redundant.

The first part replaces all RGB channels with white, but also clears the alpha channel.

```
input.png -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 reset'
```

The second part grabs the alpha channel.

```
input.png -alpha extract
```

Finally, we copy the extracted alpha values back over the white image's alpha channel.

```
-compose Copy_Alpha -composite
```

If your using ImageMagick-6, then replace `magick` with `convert`, and `Copy_Alpha` with `Copy_Opacity`.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This worked for me, but the other answer also worked and was a little simpler.